# Can we create n channel image in opencv,n will be around 20

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mat

Presently Iam working in finding disparity of stereo pair. I have got a situation in creating 20 channel data set, When I declare array of 3 dimension it was giving error, Instead can I create image of 20 channels so that I can store data. If I can what are the additional conditions I have to include to get results without any error of memory allocation or sort of ....   Creating an Image of 20 channels will be even comfortable for me...

Comment: Take a look at the `Mat` class, that allows to store n-dimensional data with n >= 2: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat

Comment: You might want to add tags for the programming languages you are interested at or include the image-processing tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C++ interface of OpenCV presents `cv::Mat`, which replaces and improves the `IplImage` type of the C interface. This new type provides several constructors, including [the one below](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat::Mat%28int%20rows,%20int%20cols,%20int%20type%29) which can be used to specify the desired number of channels through the param `type`:

```
Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type)
```

Sample code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

void test_mat(cv::Mat mat)
{
    std::cout << "Channels: " << mat.channels() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat mat20(1024, 768, CV_8UC(20));
    test_mat(mat20);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a question? I'm not sure I understood what you are trying to do.

Comment: Situation was to implement cost volume filter to find much more accurate disparity map...   as referred in paper
http://www.ims.tuwien.ac.at/research/costFilter/index.html

Comment: This could only simplify my method,, No problem I would implement with matrices only thanks for spending time on my comments...

Answer (score 3):

Opencv implements template class for small matrices whose type and size are known at compilation time:

```
template<typename _Tp, int m, int n> class Matx {...};
```

You can create a specified template of a partial case of Matx, which is cv::Vec like those already written in opencv for 1,2, or 3 "channels" like that:

```
typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b; // 3 channel -- written in opencv 
typedef Vec<uchar, 20> Vec20b; // the one you need
```

And then, declare a Matrix of your new (20 channel of uchar) object:

```
cv::Mat_<Vec20b> myMat;
myMat.at<Vec20b>(i,j)(10) = .. // access to the 10 channel of pixel (i,j)
```