# Why does cv2.threshold sometimes reduce the dimension of a numpy array?

Tags: opencv

Originally coming from a brain segmentation task i have a numpy array, which is getting thresholded via cv2.threshold. However, the thresholding reduces the dimension of the array which seems to contradict the documentation of cv2.threshold. For many other arrays coming from the same brain segmentation tool the dimension does not get reduced. Also after sorting the image linewise (mainly to enhance anonymity) the dimension gets reduced.
cv2.**version** returns 4.1.2
Does anyone have an idea how this might come, should i open a bug report?
If necessary i could also share the sorted_strange_array.npy

Input:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
strange_array = np.load("PATH/sorted_strange_array.npy")
print(strange_array.shape)
retVal, thresholded_array = cv2.threshold(strange_array, thresh=0.5, maxval=1, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
print(thresholded_array.shape)
```

Output:

```
(163, 1024, 1024)
(163, 1024)
4.1.2
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
(163, 1024, 1024)
(163, 1024, 1024)
4.1.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like OpenCV supported number of channels is [limited to 512](https://answers.opencv.org/question/46296/increase-the-maximum-amount-of-channels-in-cvmat/) channels.

The limitation is defined in the OpenCV source file [interface.h](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d10/core_2include_2opencv2_2core_2hal_2interface_8h.html)

```c++
#define CV_CN_MAX     512
```

The shape of the posted matrix is `(163, 1024, 1024)`, so it has `1024` channels, that exceeds the `512` limitation.

---

Digging into the Python binding of OpenCV, and finding the exact place where the number of channels is reduced is a challenging task.

Maybe the Python OpenCV binding has some protection, and maybe it's a bug...

---

I tried to reproduce the issue in C++:

```c++
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034222/4926757
    cv::Mat strange_array = cv::Mat(163, 1024, CV_8UC(1024));
    strange_array.setTo(100);
    cv::Mat threshold;
    cv::threshold(strange_array, threshold, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    return 0;
}
```

The size of `threshold` in the above code is 1024x163 with 512 channels.
The size of `strange_array` is also 1024x163 with 512 channels.

When using `cv::Mat(163, 1024, CV_8UC(1023))` there are `511` channels (there is an overflow without protection).

---

In general OpenCV supports matrices with up to 512 channels, so we can't say that the issue is a bug.